Cannot find custom to_timestamp SQL Function after Spring Boot 3.2.0 upgrade
I recently upgraded my Spring Boot application from Spring Boot 2.3.8 with Java 11 to Spring Boot 3.2.0 and Java 17. In my application, I’m using a PostgreSQL database, and I have a custom to_timestamp SQL function in my JPA queries to fetch records based on a dynamic time range. The query used to work perfectly in my previous setup, but since the upgrade, it’s no longer functioning as expected. It gives me below error
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select c.* customer c where to_timestamp(cast(c.created_date as text)) between to_timestamp(cast(? as text)) and to_timestamp(cast(? as text))] [ERROR: function to_timestamp(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 49] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy190.findTotalCallsAndDurationForCustomer(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at co.test.service.CustomerService.getCustomer(CustomerService.java:609) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:713) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]....
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function to_timestamp(text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


My Query
Here’s the JPA query I'm using:
select c from Customer c where to_timestamp(c.created_date) BETWEEN to_timestamp(cast(:fromtime as text)) AND to_timestamp(cast(:toTime as text))

Custom SQL Function Class
To configure the to_timestamp function, I use a custom MetadataBuilderContributor class. Here's the code I was using in Spring Boot 2.3.8:
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderContributor;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                "to_timestamp",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                        StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,
                        "to_timestamp(to_char(?1 :: timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI')::time"
                )
        );
    }
}

Additionally, I configured the contributor in my application.properties as follows:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor=com.example.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor

Attempted Solutions
After the upgrade, I tried different approaches, including:
1.Using NamedSqmFunctionDescriptor for more control over the function in Spring Boot 3.2.0.
@Component
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("to_timestamp", ToTimestampFunction.INSTANCE);
    }

    public static class ToTimestampFunction extends NamedSqmFunctionDescriptor {
        public static final ToTimestampFunction INSTANCE = new ToTimestampFunction();

        public ToTimestampFunction() {
            super("to_timestamp", false, StandardArgumentsValidators.exactly(1), null);
        }

        public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> arguments, SqlAstTranslator<?> walker) {
            Expression time = (Expression) arguments.get(0);
            sqlAppender.appendSql("to_timestamp(");
            walker.render(time, SqlAstNodeRenderingMode.DEFAULT);
            sqlAppender.appendSql(" ::text,'HH24:MI')::time");
        }
    }
}

2.Using SQL function descriptors based on other Hibernate migration guides.
Despite these efforts, the function is still not recognized correctly in the upgraded application.
Question
Has anyone successfully implemented a similar to_timestamp function in Spring Boot 3.2.0 with Java 17? Any pointers on adapting this function or the MetadataBuilderContributor for compatibility with the latest Spring Boot/Hibernate versions would be greatly appreciated!
Tried this solution as well
https://chatgpt.com/share/6721ed48-3ae8-8009-b2f1-985306a2b3a3

What's the actual error? Post the full error text. gives an error like to_timestamp function not found. doesn't explain anything. Does the error come from the database? A Java method? With the actual error one can google for similar cases, or even search the relevant library for the actual code that throws this string

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the feedback.. i have updated the question with console log error

The error comes from the database, not Spring Boot. to_timestamp requires two arguments, the data and the pattern. Are you trying to make Spring Boot translate the native to_timestamp to something else? Why? And why is to_timestamp(to_char(?1 :: timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI')::time used? What's the actual column type and why is it converted to string?

You should seriously rethink the queries and perhaps even the table design. Clauses like to_timestamp(c.created_date) BETWEEN to_timestamp(cast(:fromtime as text)) AND to_timestamp(cast(:toTime as text)) can't use indexes created on the fields themselves and require a full table scan.

@PanagiotisKanavos everything is working fine with the spring boot 2.3.8 and spring boot 2.7.x version i have tested it but when i migrated the spring boot version from 2.7.x to 3.2.0 then it gives me an above error.
also for table design i will surely rethink on it but the issue is that rightnow i am not i am stuck here and not able to find the solution that how should i compare only time with the timezone with time stamp database column typoe
